# GTK Modifying Background Color of GtkButton

Tags: c, gtk, gtk2

Trying to change background/foreground color....Using Gtk+ and C.

```
  GdkColor color;
  gdk_color_parse( "#0080FF", &color );
  gtk_widget_modify_fg( GTK_WIDGET(button), GTK_STATE_SELECTED, &color );
  gtk_widget_modify_fg( GTK_WIDGET(button), GTK_STATE_NORMAL, &color );
```

I am using above functionality but it is not giving any results.

I am looking for something asked in this question(But in C):
[GTK: create a colored regular button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241020/gtk-create-a-colored-regular-button)

how to Change Style of Button using button Style?
Can anybody provide some examples?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Picture of Red GtkButton http://www.ubuntu-pics.de/bild/30465/screenshot_001_1Jt60q.png](http://www.ubuntu-pics.de/bild/30465/screenshot_001_1Jt60q.png)

```
GdkColor color;

gdk_color_parse ("red", &color);

gtk_widget_modify_bg ( GTK_WIDGET(button), GTK_STATE_NORMAL, &color);
```

Notice that we are modifying **bg** instead of **fg**.

Comment: I have set border Relief to NONE... So it is not displaying the BG/FG color...  hot to set BG/FG color when Border Relief is None??

Comment: I do not think that is possible. When the button's border relief is set to none, it acts like a label as in it is "transparent", it has the same bg color as its parent container.

Comment: gtk_widget_modify_bg is deprecated right now. Please replace it with gtk_widget_override_background_color

Comment: Is there a way to change font color too?

Comment: Please note that ***BOTH*** `gtk_widget_override_background_color` and `gtk_widget_modify_bg` are deprecated since GTK 3.16.  
Use CSS styling or `GtkWidget::draw` signal instead

Answer (score 15):

In `GTK3` you do it using `CSS`

[image]

like this:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <string.h>

void btn_clicked(GtkWidget *widget, GtkEntry *entry);
void myCSS(void);
void createWind(GtkWidget **window, gint width, gint height);
void createGrid(GtkWidget **grid, GtkWidget **window, const gchar *name);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    GtkWidget *window, *grid;
    GtkWidget *button1, *button2, *button3, *button4;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    myCSS();

    /*     Create the Window     */
    createWind(&window, 390, 290);

    /*     Create a Grid     */
    createGrid(&grid, &window, "myGrid");


    /*     Create a red Button    */
    button1 = gtk_button_new_with_label("Red");
    gtk_widget_set_name(button1, "myButton_red");
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(button1, 160, 130);
    g_object_set (button1, "margin", 5, NULL);

    /*     Create a yellow Button    */
    button2 = gtk_button_new_with_label("Yellow");
    gtk_widget_set_name(button2, "myButton_yellow");
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(button2, 160, 130);
    g_object_set (button2, "margin", 5, NULL);

    /*     Create a green Button    */
    button3 = gtk_button_new_with_label("Green");
    gtk_widget_set_name(button3, "myButton_green");
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(button3, 160, 130);
    g_object_set (button3, "margin", 5, NULL);

    /*     Create a blue Button    */
    button4 = gtk_button_new_with_label("Blue");
    gtk_widget_set_name(button4, "myButton_blue");
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(button4, 160, 130);
    g_object_set (button4, "margin", 5, NULL);


    /*     Putting all together      */
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), button1, 0, 0, 1, 1);
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), button2, 1, 0, 1, 1);
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), button3, 0, 1, 1, 1);
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), button4, 1, 1, 1, 1);



    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}

void myCSS(void){
    GtkCssProvider *provider;
    GdkDisplay *display;
    GdkScreen *screen;

    provider = gtk_css_provider_new ();
    display = gdk_display_get_default ();
    screen = gdk_display_get_default_screen (display);
    gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen (screen, GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER (provider), GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);

    const gchar *myCssFile = "mystyle.css";
    GError *error = 0;

    gtk_css_provider_load_from_file(provider, g_file_new_for_path(myCssFile), &error);
    g_object_unref (provider);
}

void createWind(GtkWidget **window, gint width, gint height){
    *window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(*window), "MyApp");
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(*window), width, height);
    gtk_window_set_resizable (GTK_WINDOW(*window), TRUE);
    gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(*window), 5);
    g_signal_connect(*window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
}

void createGrid(GtkWidget **grid, GtkWidget **window, const gchar *name){
    *grid = gtk_grid_new ();
    gtk_grid_set_row_homogeneous(GTK_GRID(*grid), FALSE);
    gtk_grid_set_column_homogeneous(GTK_GRID(*grid), FALSE);
    gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER (*grid), 15);
    gtk_grid_set_column_spacing(GTK_GRID(*grid), 5);
    gtk_grid_set_row_spacing(GTK_GRID(*grid), 5);
    gtk_widget_set_name(*grid, name);
    g_object_set (*grid, "margin", 22, NULL);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (*window), *grid);
}

void btn_clicked(GtkWidget *widget, GtkEntry *entry){
    (void)widget;
    const gchar *gstrTexto;

    gstrTexto = gtk_entry_get_text(entry);
    g_print("%s\n", gstrTexto);
    gtk_editable_select_region(GTK_EDITABLE(entry) , 0, 3);
}
```

mystyle.css:

```
GtkWindow {
    background-color: magenta;
}

GtkButton {
    background-image: none;
}

#myGrid {
    background-color: cyan;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
}

#myChildTop {
    background-color: white;
}

#myButton_red{
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    font-family: DejaVu Sans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

#myButton_yellow{
    background-color: yellow;
    color: white;
    font-family: DejaVu Sans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

#myButton_green{
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    font-family: DejaVu Sans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

#myButton_blue{
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    font-family: DejaVu Sans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

#myButton_red:hover,
#myButton_yellow:hover,
#myButton_green:hover,
#myButton_blue:hover{
   background-color: black;
}
```

If you focus our mouse on one Button, the Button will become Black:

[image]

More about working with [GTK3 - CSS- C Language you find Here](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCeZXCNsTodx0EPcAfc6s0Ew).

Comment: Oh my gosh, thanks for this sample code, helped a lot

Comment: Well this is the reason why SO exists.

Comment: for some reason `background-color` does not work, but `background` does.