# Change colour of a button's text in Haskell (GTK)

Tags: user-interface, haskell, text, colors, gtk

How do I change the colour of a button's text in Haskell (GTK)?

The code that I am using at the moment is:

```
button <- xmlGetWidget xml castToButton "buttonLabel"
```

Should I change the colour from within the program code, or I could do it in the XML as well?

Answer (score 3):

[Gtk2hs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk-0.12.3.1) follows the GTK API very closely, so questions like this are best phrased without reference to Haskell.

I am basing my answer off the [answer for the same question in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706550/gtk-modifying-background-color-of-gtkbutton).

Basically, you have to change the colour of the *widget* (which is your button) with [`widgetModifyFg`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/gtk/0.12.3.1/doc/html/Graphics-UI-Gtk-Abstract-Widget.html#v:widgetModifyFg):

```
widgetModifyFg button StateNormal (Color 65535 0 0)
```

As to whether you should change the colour from code or XML, it depends.  If you can, it's usually best to do it declaratively in XML; otherwise, just do it programatically in code.

Comment: thanks very much for your answer. I am completely unfamiliar with the GTK API, but the suggested piece of code did no change to the colour of my button at all. I think I must be doing something not the correct way.

Comment: Do you want to change the colour of the button, or of its text?  If you want the former, you should use `widgetModifyBg` instead.  Also, could you provide a minimal example that demonstrates the problem? (maybe a few lines which create a button, change its colour, and demonstrate that the colour doesn't change)

Comment: Apologies for the late reply here. I wanted to modify the colour of the text but I gave up (as I said, it did not work with the suggested line of code). The minimal example could be basically tested with the line provided above: `button <- xmlGetWidget xml castToButton "buttonLabel"` - just create any sort of Glade XML file that contains a button and assign it to `button`. For me, it resulted in no change.