# GTK+ - setting the color of a button (in C)

Tags: c, gtk

So my problem is as follows - I need to create buttons in my GTK/C program that are simple clickable, colored tiles. I found this thread [GTK Modifying Background Color of GtkButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706550/gtk-modifying-background-color-of-gtkbutton) and a few other resources that supply a very similar answer, but no matter what I do the set_fg function does nothing and set_bg function either sets a thin frame around the button/widget - which itself stays gray - or also does nothing. Can anyone please help me solve this problem or give me a reasonable alternative to creating a set of colored tiles that can be clicked on and that can dynamically change color?

Comment: What version of GTK+?

Comment: You will need to use CSS for GTK+ 3. Look at GtkStyleContext and GtkCssProvider.